# impute error: a column has 80% missing value

Tags: r, missing-data

I need to calculate the missing values  (specific probeset)in the sample using 6 nearest neighbors and Euclidean distance with the `impute.knn()` function. I had to replace a value with NA in my dataset and then impute the missing value just to test the function

```
mat1
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4]   [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]    [,9]    [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] 8176.8 8308.4 13002.9 8385.3 8962.8 8391.5 8834.2 10978.4 11863.2 10479 51.7  171.9 581.4 161.4 167.9 25.1  213.2 122.6 81.7  111.8
> mat1[1,4] <- NA
> mat1
     [,1]   [,2]   [,3]    [,4] [,5]   [,6]   [,7]   [,8]    [,9]    [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18] [,19] [,20]
[1,] 8176.8 8308.4 13002.9 NA   8962.8 8391.5 8834.2 10978.4 11863.2 10479 51.7  171.9 581.4 161.4 167.9 25.1  213.2 122.6 81.7  111.8
> impute.knn(mat1,2)
Error in impute.knn(mat1, 2) : 
  a column has more than 80 % missing values!
```

Here is my error,, any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Note that since you have a single row, any missing value will be 100% missing values for that column. Consequently adding a NA on the column and calculating inpute.knn(mat1, 2) will result in the error message you are reading.

As has been noted several times, this is clearly stated in the documentation at `?impute.knn`:

> rowmax - The maximum percent missing data allowed in any row (default
> 50%). For any rows with more than rowmax% missing are imputed using
> the overall mean per sample.
>
> colmax - The maximum percent missing data
> allowed in any column (default 80%). If any column has more than
> colmax% missing data, the program halts and reports an error.

So the solution is to use a test matrix that is more than one row or column, and then further to adjust these arguments as needed.

Comment: mat1
      [,1]   
 [1,] 8176.8 
 [2,] 8308.4 
 [3,] 13002.9
 [4,] NA     
 [5,] 8962.8 
 [6,] 8391.5 
 [7,] 8834.2 
 [8,] 10978.4
 [9,] 11863.2
[10,] 10479  
[11,] 51.7   
[12,] 171.9  
[13,] 581.4  
[14,] 161.4  
[15,] 167.9  
[16,] 25.1   
[17,] 213.2  
[18,] 122.6  
[19,] 81.7   
[20,] 111.8  
> impute.knn(mat1)
Error in double(n) : invalid 'length' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In knnimp(x, k, maxmiss = rowmax, maxp = maxp) :
  1 rows with more than 50 % entries missing;
 mean imputation used for these rows

Comment: I have tried something like this and get this error message. I understand it probably is a very simple solution but for someone like me who is just starting out in R I would really appreciate any comments. Thank you

Comment: @user2207860 A perfectly clear explanation has been given. We literally can't do anything more at this point than to literally read the documentation to you.